# Minimum length path touching $n$ circles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, graph-theory

Given $n$ non-overlapping circles of radius $1$ (i.e., the distance between the centers of any two circles is greater than $2$), how to find the minimum length path (the path can be of any form) that touches all the circles (we say that a path touches a circle if the minimum distance between a point of the path and the center of the circle is less or equal to $1$)? Or, how to find such good paths with small lengthes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are seeking the optimal TSP disk tour, for congruent disks,
a special case of "TSP with neighborhoods."
The TSP disk-tour problem is NP-hard,
but there exists a PTAS (polynomial-time approximation scheme) for it.
See the paper by Dumitrescu & Mitchell below.
One of their algorithms achieves an approximation ratio of $1 + 8/\pi \approx 3.55$,
and is very efficient (although it would not be easy to implement).

> Dumitrescu, Adrian, and Joseph SB Mitchell. "Approximation algorithms for TSP with neighborhoods in the plane." *Proceedings of the twelfth annual ACM-SIAM symposium on Discrete algorithms (SODA)*. SIAM, 2001. ([PDF download link](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jsbm/papers/tspn-jalgorithms.pdf))

[image: Fig.1]

Comment: PTAS implies an approximation ratio arbitrarily close to 1. There is more than one algorithm in their paper, the PTAS algorithm is different from the 3.55 algorithm.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I stand corrected---Thanks. (Altered the language to avoid misleading.)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke. Thanks. But my problem is different from TSP with neighbor. I am looking for a path (that touches each circle) shorter than the path that connects the centers of each circles.

Comment: I think if you look at the paper I cited, you will find your problem is not different. Don't be misled by Fig.1.

Comment: "For example, the
neighborhoods may be disks centered at buyers’ locations, and the radius of each disk specifies the
maximum distance a buyer is willing to travel to the meeting place."